# The Stack Exchange Data Explorer throws an Index out of range error

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

It is great that [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) supports multiple result sets so you can do this in one [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/270308/sede-index-out-of-range):

```sql
select *
from tagsynonyms

select t.id
, t.sourcetagname
, t. targetTagname
, t.creationdate
, o.id as [User Link]
, t.approvaldate
from tagsynonyms t
inner join users o on o.id = t.owneruserid
```

Unfortunately using the feature of one of the magic columns (in this case `[User Link]`) throws a server-side exception :

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Removing or replacing `[User Link]` fixes this exception but that doesn't render a link to the user of course.

Can this be fixed please?

Comment: *facepalms* Oh boy, at least I don't think I'm responsible for this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a bad variable placement. [Fixed now](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/62), pending a pull and redeploy.