# Improve data.stackexchange.com error messages

Tags: bug, data-explorer

The other day, when the site went into readonly mode, I was playing around in the data explorer, which failed to complete any of the tasks (which I assume was due to the downtime).

Two of the error messages I recieved were:

[image]

and

[image]

These messages seem more like log messages that help the devs deal with errors, not the user.

I'd suggest making them more user friendly.

Comment: Agreed, can be changed to generic "Error occurred, please try again later".

Comment: Hmm, yeah, we can probably handle this specific kind of scenario.

Comment: @bluet fair enough but as Tim said we can catch errors that are not related directly to the user's query.

Answer (score 2):

No, that might not be a good idea.

That box shows any exception message that occurs. That includes screw-ups in your own Sql-syntax, or in your parameter type conversion, or in your mis-use of permissions.

If those exceptions gets filtered to a general user friendly message you have no way to know if you made a mistake. For [example this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234797/sede-reports-could-not-allocate-a-new-page-for-database-tempdb) or [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248085/the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-throws-an-index-out-of-range-error).

In case the UX people win be prepared to get a lot of false-positive bug-reports here for the data explorer simply because the sql-query or the added features contain an error while SEDE works.

There might be some clear cut cases as indicated by Tim that can be handled differently but I wonder if it is really needed given the type of application SEDE is and its users.

Comment: These errors are likely thrown when we open the connection, so we can handle them distinct from errors that occur during query execution (the ones you're referring to)

Comment: @TimStone Ok, it might be worth some investigation but you'll always end-up with exception that are beyond normal use. I don't consider it as a bad user experience if a *query developer* gets an raw exception shown based on his own attempts. And I really think the bug reports are more useful this way.

Comment: I agree with @rene. Leave the messages how they are. It's not helpful to post bug reports if you receive the same generic error message for multiple errors. Even though I didn't know what either of the two messages were talking about as shown in the OP, it helped differentiate between a resolved bug and new bug that started like a day after the previous different bug.

Comment: I guess the proposal from Tim needs some love. We could take a look if there is a clear way to shield let's say infrastructure exceptions from *normal* use exceptions as long as we agree that exceptions being thrown is part of the *normal* operation/required functionality for SED and it's raw unshielded message being displayed to the SEDE user.